# How to throttle the amount of request to an API?

Tags: api, apache-kafka, crm, throttling, rate-limiting

There is a crm system, which provides webhooks to notify about some events happening in it (for instance, user creates some entity or moves it to the next 'status'). At some event a webhook triggers my script, that creates a new entity in this crm system using it's API. The system's API has a rate limit – 7 request per second. By violating this rule the access to the API may be restricted for the account for some time.

The problem is, that if user changes 'status' of 1000 entities the webhook triggers my script 1000 times, so it calls the API 1000 times and that may violate the rate limit. Is there any way to temporarily 'store' all requests that came from the webhook and then launch the script no more than n-times per second?

The script is written in php and is located on my Apache server now, but later it may be put on client's server or somewhere else.

I've read about Rabbit MQ and Kafka. But it seems to be an overkill for this task. Or maybe it's OK? I just don't have enough experience with these systems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some database available to store the Webhook Request?

Comment: Hi! I think that I can create one. Maybe you know any code examples (js or php) how I can make it with a database?